# When did Clang gain support for C++11's alignof keyword?

Tags: clang++, alignof

Clang first claimed support, via `__has_feature(cxx_alignof)`, for C++11's `alignof` keyword in [r223186](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-commits/Week-of-Mon-20141201/119331.html) (December 2014).  This corresponds to Clang 3.6 by the Clang project's marketing version number.

But that revision *only* implements the feature-test: `alignof` support happened earlier.  Indeed, [Clang's C++ status page](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) says `alignof` was implemented in Clang 3.3!

I work on a project that requires Clang 3.3 (or its equivalent) but not yet Clang 3.6.  Are there bugs in Clang 3.3-3.5's `alignof` implementation that delayed feature-testing support, or was non-support merely an oversight?  Can I safely use `alignof` in this project, even though `__has_feature(cxx_alignof)` might claim `alignof` isn't supported?